# Why do we need to build photon colliders? Since electron-position colliders are very "clean"

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, gamma-rays, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

What's the advantage of gamma-gamma colliders? What new physics can be done with it?

Reference: http://www.slac.stanford.edu/pubs/beamline/26/1/26-1-kim.pdf

Comment: Details, please. The article would seem to answer your questions. Why doesn't it? Include this explanation in your question.

Comment: The academic papers may be too hard to understand, and only focus on a specific area. So I want to learn more. I hope someone can give a more general and easier to understand answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The strongest physics quest for a $\gamma\gamma$ collider is the production of Higgs bosons as the only particle in the final state, from a very well known initial state.

This is not achieved neither at future lepton colliders (ILC, CLIC, FCC-ee, CEPC) where the typical production by higgstrahlung comes with additional particles in the final state (carrying some uncertainty), and even less at proton colliders (LHC) where the initial state is unknown and there is additional noise from the proton remnants. Off course this didn't prevent its discovery, but makes precision studies much harder.

If the diphoton signal at $750~$GeV observed in the 2015 run of the LHC is confirmed, it would be a very strong push, although reaching that energy with a $\gamma\gamma$ collider is... let's say *expensive*!

Comment: Why is Higgs production a background? Wouldn't it be signal?

Comment: @innisfree unlucky choice of words, my bad

Comment: How can be the production of Higgs bosons in $\gamma\gamma$ colliders *direct*, if photons don't couple with the Higgs?

Comment: @Bosoneando They couple through loops where typically a top quark or a W boson circulates; therefore, although technically not *direct*, still as clean as if it was.

Comment: @DarioP exactly my point. The Feynman diagram for gluon fusion (which is the dominant mode at LHC) is exactly the same as the Feynman diagram for the photon fusion that you propose. By the way, in a $e^+e⁻$ collider, Higgs bosons are produced in *simpler* processes with no loops. See for example fig 2.6 in http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.6352v1

Comment: @Bosoneando Who cares if you have loops? What matters are the initial and final states. All those Higgstrahlung processes come with additional particles in the final states that introduce (small) uncertainty. The LHC is a different matter as you have no clue of the momentum carried by the involved gluons, plus there is noise coming from the proton remnants.

Comment: @DarioP that's a much better answer to the OP that your current answer

Comment: @Bosoneando thanks for the discussion, I improved the answer ;)